# Event handler works with console application, but not forms application (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, events

I am setting up an event handler to respond to serial communication.

The following code runs perfectly, and displays the received data to the console

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO.Ports

Module Module1

    Sub DataReceivedHandler(
                        sender As Object,
                        e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)
        Dim sp As SerialPort = CType(sender, SerialPort)
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
        Dim indata As String = sp.ReadExisting()
        Console.Write(indata)
    End Sub

    Sub Main()
        Dim mySerialPort As New SerialPort("COM2")

        mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600
        mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None
        mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One
        mySerialPort.DataBits = 8
        mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None
        mySerialPort.RtsEnable = True

        AddHandler mySerialPort.DataReceived, AddressOf DataReceivedHandler

        mySerialPort.Open()

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...")
        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.ReadKey()
        mySerialPort.Close()
    End Sub

End Module
```

However, this code, which is the exact same thing, just used in a form app runs, but fails to display any messages.

```
Imports System.IO.Ports

Public Class Form1


    Sub DataReceivedHandler(
                        sender As Object,
                        e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)
        Dim sp As SerialPort = CType(sender, SerialPort)
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
        Dim indata As String = sp.ReadExisting()
        MsgBox(indata)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim mySerialPort As New SerialPort("COM2")

        mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600
        mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None
        mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One
        mySerialPort.DataBits = 8
        mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None
        mySerialPort.RtsEnable = True
        AddHandler mySerialPort.DataReceived, AddressOf DataReceivedHandler
        mySerialPort.Open()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: `which is the exact same thing`  where is the `AddHandler ` for the second?

Comment: It's there now, I had moved it somewhere else for testing and forgot to put it back before posting the question. Thanks

Comment: do not use MsgBox, use Debug.Print. You are calling MsgBox on a thread which is not the message thread of the winform app.

Comment: Thanks Crisim! If you want to post that as an answer I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do not use `MsgBox`, use `Debug.Print`.

You are calling MsgBox on a thread which is NOT the message thread of the winform app.